# What is the best way to join multiple jdbc connection tables in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to migrate a query to pyspark and need to join multiple tables in it. All the tables in question are in Redshift and I'm using the jdbc connector to talk to them.

My problem is how do I do these joins optimally without reading too much data in (i.e. load table and join on key) and without just blatantly using:

```
spark.sql("""join table1 on x=y join table2 on y=z""")
```

Is there a way to pushdown the queries to Redshift but still use the Spark df API for writing the logic and also utilizing df from spark context without saving them to Redshift just for the joins?

Comment: which connector are you using? is it https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

Comment: @Salim I'm using the amazon Redshift JDBC connector
JDBC 4.2–compatible driver
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html
But I can switch to the Databricks driver if that gives me an optimal solution.

Comment: The documentation says it supposed predicate push down. I have not used either to provide a practical perspective however I can speak theoretically

Answer (score 1):

Please find next some points to consider:

- The [connector](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) will push-down the specified filters only if there is any filter specified in your Spark code e.g `select * from tbl where id > 10000`. You can confirm that by yourself, just check the responsible Scala [code](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/FilterPushdown.scala). Also [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/184b4428c1505dff7b4365963dc344197a92baa9/src/test/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/FilterPushdownSuite.scala#L52) is the corresponding test which demonstrates exactly that. The test `test("buildWhereClause with multiple filters")` tries to verify that the variable `expectedWhereClause` is equal to `whereClause` generated by the connector. The generated where clause should be:

```
"""
        |WHERE "test_bool" = true
        |AND "test_string" = \'Unicode是樂趣\'
        |AND "test_double" > 1000.0
        |AND "test_double" < 1.7976931348623157E308
        |AND "test_float" >= 1.0
        |AND "test_int" <= 43
        |AND "test_int" IS NOT NULL
        |AND "test_int" IS NULL
      """
```

which has occurred from the `Spark-filters` specified above.

- The driver supports also `column filtering`. Meaning it will load only the required columns by pushing down the valid columns to redshift. You can again verify that from the corresponding Scala [test("DefaultSource supports simple column filtering")](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/184b4428c1505dff7b4365963dc344197a92baa9/src/it/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftReadSuite.scala#L132) and [test("query with pruned and filtered scans")](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/master/src/it/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftReadSuite.scala#L143).
- Although in your case, you haven't specified any filters in your join query hence Spark can not leverage the two previous optimisations. If you are aware of such filters please feel free to apply them though.
- Last but not least and as Salim already mentioned, the official Spark connector for redshift can be found [here](http://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift). The Spark connector is built on top of [Amazon Redshift JDBC Driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) therefore it will try to use it anyway as specified on the connector's [code](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/184b4428c1505dff7b4365963dc344197a92baa9/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala#L71).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of spark pushing down filters to the database for optimization. In this case I don't know the filters. The tables are filtered on the join condition directly and I don't think pulling the table out and creating a list of values in join column and using it to filter the other table is a good idea. As the question states, I'm interested in finding a way to run multiple joins without just writing sql and without saving the df in memory to Redshift just for one join. Thanks

Comment: I think in this case (without knowing any filter) the result will be the same as in any RDBMS which is to scan both tables for the keys and then to apply the join operation. Each RDBMS has internal mechanisms for applying optimisations during large operations aka join, groupBy, sort etc I am not aware of any Spark mechanism which leverages these RDBMS features

Comment: Above I pointed out all the available optimisations for redshift in order to make clear which part of the redshift driver are responsible for which optimisations. If you check the connector code and the responsible parts (FilterPushdown.scala, RedshiftReadSuite.scala etc) you will quickly realise that there is no filter related to joins.

Comment: Correct, so what is your recommendation in this case. Should I save the spark df to a table and write a SQL query to do the joins and let Redshift optimize my query as much as possible?

Comment: My recommendation would be to find one or more fields to apply filtering. It could be anything from productId, categoryId, insertedAt, modifiedAt etc. Then you use the filter along with join. For instance if that filter is an integer you could join on ranges 1st batch 1-100, 2nd 101-200, 3rd 201-300 etc